# Pandas original Dataframe altered

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

There is a data frame created from csv from Pandas Guide example:
For example:

```
 cast=pd.read_csv('cast.csv', index_col=none, encoding='utf-8')
cast.head()

title year
0 Macbeth 1913
1 Macbeth 1997
2 Macbeth 1998
3 Macbeth 2006
```

then we do this

```
 c = casts
 c.groupby( [c['year']//10*10, 'type'] ).size().head(8)
```

Because c data frame is mutable object, so we modified year column by doing
c['year']//10*10, then we feed c['year']//10*10 as pandas series object to group by

question 1 :
as c['year']//10*10 is series object, we can either using column name, or series data as groupby aggregate attributes right?

question 2:
When we modified c['year']//10*10, we literlly modified c['year'] column value, in the other words the c data frame has been modified.
Isn't cast data frame be modified as well? because c is only the alias of cast?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two questions.

As to your first question, [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) accepts a column name, series, NumPy arrays and lists, callables, or possibly a dictionary.

Regarding your second question, `c` is an alias for `casts`, yes, but the arithmetic operations result in a new series being returned. No modifications are made to the original unless you assign back.